# Save perspective containing multiple instances of the same view

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

My understanding of the situation:

There are two ways to persist state of views in Eclipse:

- Mementos: these are saved on workbench close and restored on open
- IDialogSettings: these can be saved and restored at will

[PackageExplorerPart](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/packageview/PackageExplorerPart.java) in Eclipse uses both for (e.g.) linking files in the explorer to editors.

I have multiple instances of the same view with different state, and I want to save them in a perspective.  If I save using mementos, closing and opening Eclipse will restore the state correctly.

If I open a new window with File | New Window, my saved perspective **does not provide mementos nor secondary IDs** to the views, so they cannot restore.

Is there a way to save the state of these views so that the perspective can be correctly restored?

Answer (score 0):

While technically DialogSettings can be used to persist view state, only Mementos passed to `saveState()` and `init()` are meant therefore.

Not sure why the package explorer does such *double-entry book keeping*. There will probably be a reson for, but I haven't had the necessity to do so.

*New Window* creates a new view and hence there is nothing to restore. If you restart Eclipse with two windows open, both will be restored and the views within as well.

If you would like to restore a new view with the state of another view of the same type you will have to take for that yourself (without workbench support).

For example, you could store the Memento passed to `saveState()` in a well-known location and load this state when a new view is to be opened.

Comment: The aim is to save and restore a perspective containing these views.  When the new view is created I don't know where within the perspective it is located, so I don't know which state to reload.

Comment: So you want an exact copy of the current perspective when a new window is opened?

Comment: Not exactly.  I want to be able to save the arrangement as a perspective.  If you open a new window in Eclipse it will give you a "reset" version of whatever perspective you are in.  That's what I want, but I want to be able to save the contents of views within that perspective.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it: "but I want to save the contents of views ..." -> that's what `saveState()` is for. If there are multiple instances of the same view, use `getViewSite().getSecondaryId()` to distinguish them.

Comment: When a new window is creating these views, neither a memento nor a secondary id are provided.